# Simple object count on frame with Yolo has error Not enough values to unpack

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo, darknet, yolov4

I'm trying to count the number of cars visible in a frame. Here is an excerpt:

```
while True:
    # Read frame from video
    ret, frame = cv2.VideoCapture(input_video).read()
    if not ret:
        break
    
    # Detect objects in the frame using Darknet
    darknet_output = proc.stdout.readline().decode()
    if darknet_output.startswith("Enter Image Path:"):
        darknet_output = proc.stdout.readline().decode()
    objects = []
    while darknet_output.strip() != "":
        objects.append(darknet_output.strip())
        darknet_output = proc.stdout.readline().decode()
        
    # Count the number of cars detected in the frame
    car_count = 0
    for obj in objects:
        obj_class, obj_confidence, (x, y, w, h) = obj.split()
        if obj_class == "car":
            car_count += 1
    
    # Draw text on the top of the frame with the car count
    cv2.putText(frame, "Cars: {}".format(car_count), org, font, font_scale, color, thickness, cv2.LINE_AA)
    
    # Display the frame with the car count
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

The error that I'm having is

```
line 54, in module obj_class, obj_confidence, (x,y,w,h) = obj.split() ValueError: not enough values to unpack ( expected 3, got 1)
```

The main goal I'm trying to achieve is output a value on top of the screen of car objects. Is there a better way to do this?